# Checkbox and onchange method usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, onchange

I have a table with some rows that have checkboxes on the first column where if user clicks, it calls some javascript methods that disable the other fields of the respective rows.

The structure of these inputs is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ans_R2057321_Q2060122" id="ans_R2057321_Q2060122" value="2002241" onclick="matrix.disableFields(this, 'R2057321');recalculateRowFormulas('2057321'); alignTDs();" />
```

I implemented a link where when user clicks on it, it has to select all these checkboxes, so I did it this way:

```
function noQuoteAllRowsOfCurrPage(){
    jQuery("input:checkbox[id^=ans_R]").each(function(i,e) {
        jQuery(e).prop('checked', true);
    });
}
```

This simply iterates in each checkbox on the screen whose id starts with ans_R, and then check the CB state to true. It does works, but the problem is that the javascript functions called on the onclick property of the input checkboxes aren't running. First thing I did was changing from onclick to onchange, which should be the correct way to do that, since the state of checkbox is changing, but somehow it doesn't work... any ideas what of what can I do?

Comment: Please don't use inline event handling like that -- it's god awful to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was missing and since I saw several people with the same problem, I think my solution can be helpful for others..

I just added a trigger for 'change'.

```
function noQuoteAllRowsOfCurrPage(){
    jQuery("input:checkbox[id^=ans_R]").each(function(i,e) {
        jQuery(e).click();
        jQuery(e).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no change event bound to the elements

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's `.prop()` function does not trigger the change event. You either can

**1 - Trigger the event manually**

```
jQuery(e).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

**2 - Use the `.click()` function that will check the input, and trigger the event as well..**

```
jQuery(e).click();
```

Comment: @Periback Have you consider triggering both? `jQuery(e).prop('checked', true).trigger('change').trigger('click');`

Comment: I combined your second idea with mine (which is your first one), and it worked as I was expecting... (I found there were lots of other javascript codes  were impacting mine..)

Comment: I did exactly what you just said (I had the page opened here so I hadn't get your updated comment)

Comment: just one thing.. I have to trigger the click, before the change... and for some reason it didn't work by using it on one line as you sugested... see my updated answer